# What is the best way to patch a Java app bundle on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, patch, auto-update

I am developing software for Linux, Windows and Mac and distribute the software outside app stores. The software is digitally signed (of course) and I use app bundles with embeded jre on Mac and comparable solutions on Windows (there installed with NSIS and launch4j launcher). So far, I did not find practical solutions for updating / patching Mac OS X app bundles, and I am wondering, if there is any solution at all to this problem apart from completely replacing the app bundle. I read about sparkle, but since I do not use XCode but Java / Eclipse, it is pretty hard to get it to work.

Is there a way to write into an existing app bundle with another app, which has been signed with the same signature?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this in a proper way? I am facing the same issue. I use javapackager for mac package creation. On windows I have two executables, the first is just checking if the second needs updating and overwrites it fully when it does. But on mac, I cannot find a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to automatically update/patch/slice *signed* Java app bundles on macOS without replacing them with the updated version altogether.

Theoretically, you could patch your signed application by scripting the replacement of the appropriate JARs/files/etc. and then updating the signature in the app bundle directory:

> /Contents/_MASReceipt/

I haven't tried this myself so I don't have much else to offer there, but it should be workable.

**Generic / Alternative Info:**

In case this helps:  In general, making Java applications blend well with macOS involves using XCode's JarBundler and/or external build plugins (using Ant and/or Maven). If you want more information on those things, some references follow.

- Packaging your Java app for macOS using Xcode/JarBundler:
  https://alvinalexander.com/apple/mac/java-jar-bundler/
- Using Ant tasks to handle the packaging in automated build scripts:
  https://alvinalexander.com/apple/mac/java-jar-bundler/Jar_Bundler_as_Ant_task.shtml
- Using Apple's Java libraries and Maven plugins to package your app:
  https://blog.lerk.io/packaging-a-jar-as-app-for-macos/

It sounds like you might already know these things, but maybe it will be helpful for others reading.